# Setting Django admin display times to local time?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I see dates and times in the admin, they are displayed in UTC. I'd like for them to be displayed in my local timezone. I checked the `TIME_ZONE` setting in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#time-zone), though it doesn't look like that is quite what I want. `TIME_ZONE` determines the time zone for the datetimes stored in the database, which is not what I want to set -- I just want to `localize` the time zones for the admin, but not change how they are saved at the database level.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

In Django：

The **default time zone** is the time zone defined by the TIME_ZONE setting.

The **current time zone** is the time zone that’s used for rendering.

so you should set the **"current time zone"** use:

> django.utils.timezone.activate(timezone)

You can activate it in a middleware(don't forger to register it to MIDDLEWARE in settings.py):

```
import pytz    
from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
        return self.get_response(request)
```

This is only a simple hardcode. you can making a form to select tzinfo, store it in user's profile and load it to user session, read the tzinfo from the session in the middleware.

The official documentation has a related description:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Reference：

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/E4aiv3O6vGo

Comment: In Python 3.9+, you do not need `pytz` and can pass either a string to `activate` or a `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo` object.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't supported natively in Django as of 2.1. However https://github.com/charettes/django-sundial may provide what you need -- this adds a `User.timezone` model field so that you can configure it per-user.

(This middleware is very simple -- under the covers it's just calling `timezone.activate(zone)` to change the rendered site's timezone).

Answer (score 2):

You can override the template for your `change_list.html`, `change_form.html`, etc. and do something like:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load tz %}

{% block content %}
    {% timezone "US/Eastern" %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endtimezone %}
{% endblock %}
```

Do it with one of those methods:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options

Comment: I follow this but for certain forms it seems to update the datetime without the timezone offset. Have you noticed this?

Comment: It's been a while since a last tried this. Anything special about those forms or fields that are different?

Comment: nope, If you follow the directions you gave you'll notice that the date edit fields accept UTC. So to sidestep the issue I just make sure to edit ALL dates in UTC before saving the model.

Answer (score -9):

Maybe you can try to set user timezone.
Set

```
 USE_TZ = True
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: I already have it set to true -- that setting controls whether or not one is using timezone-aware dates.